# Save changes to Property File in Grails

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, grails-2.0

I have a grails application that reads from a property file.  I created an administration page, that allows the user to view the settings in this file.  I want to allow the user to update the various properties and save them back to the property file using Grails.

My problem is I cant seem to figure out how to save the changes back to the property file.

Here is my code that reads from the file and makes changes to the properties:

```
  def env = params.getAt("environment");
    if (env != null){
     //Read from Property file based on user selection
        def props = new Properties()
        def cl = Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader
        def filepath = env+'.properties'
        props.load  servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/"+ filepath)

        Enumeration e = props.propertyNames();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = (String) e.nextElement();
            def input = params.getAt(key)
            if (input != null){
                props.setProperty(key,input)
            }
        }
         //props.store(propFile.newWriter(), null)

    }
```

Any Ideas on how to save/overwrite the example.properties file in /WEB-INF/example.properties?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you might be looking for the *getRealPath* method in *ServletContext* 
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String)

Simple example that shows you how to use it

```
http://82.157.70.109/mirrorbooks/javaservletjspcookbook/0596005725_jsvltjspckbk-chp-14-sect-7.html
```

Comment: The link you posted doesn't seem to work. So I need to use get real path but don't I need to write back to the property file through an outputstream? Not sure how to do in groovy/grails

Comment: If you get the real path of let's say web-inf, then you can find the absolute path to your file, then you can open an outputstream just like in plain Java using properties.store(See java.util.Properties javadoc) for example... I hope it helps.